# How can I list people who have starred my GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I'm curious as to who has starred a GitHub repo of mine, so I'd like a list of users who have starred it. Is this possible to get?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

To get a list of users that have starred a repository you can append `/stargazers` to the URL of the repository

If you have a repository at the following address

```
https://github.com/strugee/battleship
```

To see a list of users that have starred that repository visit the following URL

```
https://github.com/strugee/battleship/stargazers
```

Comment: For some reason, you can no longer reach the /stargazers page by clicking on the number. I wonder why they removed this functionality? The itself page still exists.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Please see this answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/162995/224477

Answer (score 45):

[image: Stargazers]

These information is now available in the About section of the repository on the right side of the page beside the code section. The numbers before 'star' and 'watching' are clickable.

Answer (score 11):

You can also see who the watchers are (previous comment is incorrect):

```
https://github.com/[user]/[repo]/watchers
```

Comment: please explain your claim that "previous comment is incorrect". what are you referring to?

Comment: He's referring to Hydra's comment that you can only see watchers with the API.

Comment: This answer should be removed and posted as a comment of Hydra's answer, since it's not an answer to the OP's question at all. Or ideally edit Hydra's answer.

Comment: What about forks?

Answer (score 5):

Other than the web interface, you can also use [the API](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#list-stargazers) that GitHub provides to query the users that starred your repository.

With the API, you can also check who is watching your repository, which I believe isn't possible in the web interface.

Answer (score 2):

I created a python package "github-email-explorer" that you can use a command to get a email list from a repo for understanding who have starred.

Here's an example:

```
$ ge-explore --repo yuecen/github-email-explorer --action_type star fork watch
```

The result looks like,

```
User A <user.a@example.net>; User B <user.b@example.net>
```

To get more detail, check it out: **https://github.com/yuecen/github-email-explorer**

Comment: thanks for the tip, and welcome to Stack Exchange! if you wrote a tool you're linking to (and it seems like you did), it's best practice here to disclose that fact. you can do this by clicking the [edit] button.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I modified some description for it.